# createjs - way to initialize rotated rectangle?

Tags: createjs

Is there a way to initialized a rotated rectangle without animating its rotation first?

```
stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
//Create a Shape DisplayObject.
rect = new createjs.Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(100, 100, 40, 40);//these are the x, y, w, and h. But no arguments for rotating?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to rotate the graphics themselves? There is not really a way to do this - the `rect` simply proxies the canvas2d methods.

You can set rotation on initialization of any shape you want...

```
var s = new createjs.Shape(rect).set({rotation: 45});
```

I am not sure the benefit of rotating the actual coordinates themselves.

Comment: not the coordinates, just the shape. this is good, thanks